# KnowledgeValidationStatus unable to retrieve metadata

Tags: deployment, knowledge

I am unable to pull the new picklist values from Knowledge Validation Status field encounter this error

unpackaged/package.xml  Unable to retrieve file for id 60 (KnowledgeValidationStatus). This Standard Value Set is either inaccessible or not supported in Metadata API.

Already tried using the force:source:retrieve -m 'StandardValueSet' and the force:source:pull -f, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Currently, 'KnowledgeValidationStatus' doesn't support StandardValueSet as per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm) and this seem to be working as designed.

Thanks

Comment: do you have a workaround on how to deploy this component?

Comment: I don't think we have any workaround at moment.